# Redirect back Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I have a form filter and a grid with result data. In table i click on a field and update this field,in controller return Redirect::back(), in this case all field from form are reseted, but i need to keep this value. Field what is pressed is out of this form.How can resolve this problem?

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'admin/filter', 'method'=>'put','class' => 'navbar-form']) !!}
//text fields for filter
{!!Form::close!!}

table
<td>
@if($mark->enabled==1)
<p>
{!! HTML::link('admin/showEnabled/'.$mark->id,'', ['class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open']) !!}
</p>
@else
<p>
{!! HTML::link('admin/showEnabled/'.$mark->id, '',['class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close']) !!}
</p>
    @endif
<td>
</table>
--------------
Cotroller admin showEnabled
update field
Redirect::back()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `withInput()` chaining method:

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput();
```

Or, in the latest version:

```
return back()->withInput();
```